# How to clone only public_html into folder on server?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I've version-controlled my entire project on my local machine, and now I essentially want to use Mercurial to upload all my files to my server and keep it up to date.

I have a `public_html` folder which is a subfolder of the project root. I only want to clone that folder into a specific folder with a different name on my server (it's called `htdocs` on the server, and can't be renamed).

Is this possible? How?

Comment: I ended up cloning my project to a completely different folder and then just creating a symlink to the `public_html` folder where I needed it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't clone only a portion of a repository.  If you want only public_html it needs to be its own repository.